# Node accepted new socket connection even when main thread is blocked #3473

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp, event-loop, epoll

Node.js Version: v10.19.0
OS: Ubuntu 18
Scope (install, code, runtime, meta, other?):
Module (and version) (if relevant): http

```
const http =  require('http');

const server = http.createServer((req,res)=>{
    console.log('a new http request');    
    let d = Date.now();

    while(Date.now()-d <  50000) {
    // block for 50 seconds here
    }
});

server.on('connection',function(){
    console.log('new connection');
});
server.listen(3500);
```

so I have a http server starting at 3500 in the request handler im blocking for 50 seconds on each request, now from terminal I hit 3 curl one after the other, I see new connection gets printed and then a new http request, then after 50 seconds I see another new connection gets printed and so on , but if i run the command netstat -an -p tcp | grep 3500 , just after hitting 3 back to back curl , I can see 6 socket connection already established ( 2 for each curl), My question since node uses a single thread and wait on epoll , after it has accepted first connection and created a new socket for it, its blocking for next 50 seconds, then how other 2 connection got established, below is the result of netstat after running three back to back curl localhost:3500

```
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:35998 127.0.0.1:3500 ESTABLISHED 4286/curl
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:36000 127.0.0.1:3500 ESTABLISHED 4292/curl
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:35996 127.0.0.1:3500 ESTABLISHED 4281/curl
tcp6 2 0 :::3500 :::* LISTEN 4238/node
tcp6 78 0 127.0.0.1:3500 127.0.0.1:35998 ESTABLISHED -
tcp6 0 0 127.0.0.1:3500 127.0.0.1:35996 ESTABLISHED 4238/node
tcp6 78 0 127.0.0.1:3500 127.0.0.1:36000 ESTABLISHED -
```

Answer (score 2):

The connection establishment is done in the OS kernel, no matter if the application is busy doing stuff or not. The established connection is then propagated to the application when the app is calling `accept`, which is done by node. You can see that the request is not actually handled yet by the application since there is only a single `new connection`, i.e. the one from the first call of curl.

Comment: Okay, but node event loop use epoll and blocks until it accepts a connection on listening socket, which creates a new socket, but the other 2 new socket has already been created after first curl, then who accepted the incoming connection, im coming from this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P9csgxBgaZ8&t=665s, and what do you mean app is calling accept , you mean listening socket accepting the connection and giving it a new dedicated socket, another question is tcp handshake already been done for other 2 sockets after first curl

Comment: @TarunPrakashSingh: *"...  then who accepted the incoming connection,"* - as I said, the connection establishment is done already __inside the operating system kernel, outside of the application__. Having this established connection is sufficient for curl to send its request.

Comment: so tcp handshake already done on kernel level and listening socket accepted the connection and dedicated new socket to client, all this has happened when node was blocking after first curl request?

Comment: @TarunPrakashSingh: yes, all of this was done without the application even being involved.

Comment: but the video i pasted that guy said that in event loop code it is written that its a semiinfinte loop waiting on epoll and when it has some connection u accept it and a new socket is created, so after first cul u accept the connection and new socket is created and then theres just while loop for 50 seconds so i was guessing only after 50 s seconds , u get new connection from epoll on second event loop iteration, can u check this video in middle  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P9csgxBgaZ8&t=665s from 10 minute mark please

Comment: @TarunPrakashSingh: The meaning of *"accept the connection"* depends on the context.  It might mean that the kernel accepts the connection by completing the TCP handshake - which is independent of the application. It might mean that the applications accepts the *already established* connection when calling `accept`. From the perspective of the client only the first (kernel only part) is relevant for connection establishment.

Comment: so u saying tcp handshake is done at kernel and accept is called on node, but i see new socket already in netstat that means connection has already been accepted, which system call u referring when saying accept , i guess u saying listening socket accepts it and new socket is created that is what accept is, but the video says all this happens in node

Comment: Again - please distinguish between what is happening in the OS kernel and what is happening in the application. The video only talks about the application side. The TCP handshake is done inside the kernel though and the application gets the already established socket when calling `accept`. And if you still don't understand this I give up explaining since I'm not able to give the same answer as I gave multiple times before in yet another slightly different wording.

Comment: no issues Steffen, thanks for being patience and thanks for the answer

Comment: It helped me a lot reading through this conversation.

Comment: looks like syn syn/ack ack is done by kernel, and node is not aware of it.  server.on(xxx) doesn't fire since node thread is busy. but the connection is established by kernel already. Then when node thread gets a chance, it 'accepts' connection from kernel, and server.on(xxx) is executed followed by request.